How common is it to ask new company for a start date 1 month from signing offer letter?
I signed my offer letter beginning of this month and asked if I can start beginning of next month. Is that reasonable? The company put my anticipated start date to only 1 week from when they sent the offer letter. When asked about the flexibility of this date, the recruiter flipped out saying something about candidates backing out of their word. I am assuming something like this happened before for him to react the way he did.
I emailed the hiring manager directly to ask for more time to give sufficient notice to my employer as well as give myself some time to recharge. Currently waiting anxiously to hear back and wondering if my ask is reasonable?

Where are you located? Do you have an obligatory notice period with your current employer? Why did you sign the offer letter if you didn't agree with the start date on it?

Im in the east coast. I dont have a notice period. I signed the offer letter because the recruiter grumpily said the start date could be adjusted after I sign.

Please add tag [tag:united-states] and or a tag for the relevant state. For example, in Europe it is pretty common to have a notice period of one calendar month or more, so people starting 1, 2, 3 or even more months later is absolutely normal, on the other hand in the US it is probably less so with their short or even absent notice periods.

This should have been addressed before you signed the offer letter. You asked about a specific start date, but the offer letter didn't reflect that date. However, you signed it anyway. When you signed it, you agreed to it. So, on one hand, I can understand the recruiter's perspective.
Without being privy to the exact communication, however, the recruiter "flipping out" and saying that you are "backing out of your word" does seem excessive and unprofessional. However, without more details, it's hard to say. Expressing disappointment would be expected in this situation, though.
The biggest problem that I see is that the reasons you're asking for more time aren't things that came up after you signed the letter. Sometimes, unexpected things happen. However, giving a sufficient notice period to transition your work or the desire to have a short break between jobs is normal and something that should be considered early.
It's hard to say how the hiring manager would respond. On the surface, the request doesn't seem unreasonable, but it does depend on the new company's onboarding processes. The response may give you insight into the company's culture.

It is entirely reasonable to say "I have some personal commitments I'd like to follow through on; can we delay my start date a few weeks?"
It doesn't matter whether those commitments are to others or to your family or to yourself. If you just want to take a quick vacation before starting, that's sufficient justification to ask.
They may say "we really need you sooner than that." In which case you need to decide what your own priorities are and how hard you are willing to push for this. Push too hard and you could lose the offer.
But just asking should do no harm at all.
